# Nothing executes after startWith operator in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Trying to follow Jake Wharton's example in [Managing State with RxJava](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4)

My code works fine **without** the `startWith` operator, but as soon as I add it, only the `startWith` item is emitted, and the rest of the chain does not execute.

Here's the calling function:

```
compositeDisposable.add(
            Observable
                .just(myUpdateProfileEvent)
                .compose(update())
                .subscribe({ state.value = it }, { Timber.e(it) })
)
```

And my transformer:

```
fun update(): ObservableTransformer<UpdateProfileEvent, ProfileModel> {
    return ObservableTransformer {
        it.flatMap {
            api
                .updateUser( … user params …)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext { saveUser(it) }
                .map { ProfileModel.UpdateSuccessful(it) as ProfileModel }
                .onErrorReturn { ProfileModel.UpdateError(it) as ProfileModel }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .startWith { ProfileModel.UpdateInProgress() as ProfileModel } <--- This is the line in question
        }
    }
```

If I remove the `.startWith` line, everything executes as expected.

However, after adding `.startWith`, only `ProfileModel.UpdateInProgress()` is emitted and nothing else after that -- `api.updateUser()`, etc. is never executed.

Help!

Thanks

Comment: Use `startWith ( ProfileModel.UpdateInProgress() as ProfileModel )`.

Comment: @akarnokd That worked!